# Find the value of integral with logarithmic

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

How to find the following integral $$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{\log^2(x)}dx$$
I am trying in the following way.
After the change of variable,the above becomes $$\int_{\log 2}^{\infty}x^{-2}e^{-x}dx$$

Now then I am stuck.

Comment: Can you say more?

Comment: WolframAlpha uses the [logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Integral_representation) to write the result, which is $\mathrm{li}(1/2)+1/\log 4 \approx 0.342676$. I tried solving it using elementary methods, but I could not.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct and elementary way of obtaining the WolfamAlpha result is to replace a factor $1$ in the integrand with $\frac{x}{x}$ and then to proceed by integrating by parts, thus

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{x}{x\log^2 (x)} \, dx= \left[x\int \frac{1}{x \log ^2(x)} \,dx \right]_0^{\frac{1}{2}}- \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}1 \times \int \frac{1}{x \log^2 (x)} \, dx\, dx$$

Since $$\int \frac{1}{x \log^2 (x)} \, dx=-\frac{1}{\log(x)}+C$$ we have

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{\log^2 (x)} \, dx= \left[-\frac{x}{\log(x)} \right]_0^{\frac{1}{2}}- \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \left(-\frac{1}{\log(x)}\right)\, dx$$

Answer (score 0):

As you said:
$$\int_0^{1/2}\frac1{\ln^2x}dx=\int_{\ln2}^\infty x^{-2}e^{-x}dx=\Gamma(-1,\ln2)$$
as the incomplete gamma function is defined as:
$$\Gamma(s,x)=\int_x^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$